# Polars - ComputeError: cannot cast 'Object' type after conversion from Numpy Array

Tags: python, python-polars

I have a polars dataframe which I split into multiple frames using np.array_split. After the split and the conversion back to the polars dataframe all columns have the data type 'object'. When I want to change the data type using cast() I get the following error:
ComputeError: cannot cast 'Object' type
What am I doing wrong?/How can I fix this? I need the columns to be different data types for further processing.

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'column1': ['2021-01-01', '2021-02-02', '2021-03-03'],
    'column2': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
})

df = pl.from_numpy(np.array_split(df, 2)[0], schema=df.columns, orient='row')
df = df.with_columns(pl.col('column1').cast(pl.Utf8))
```

Comment: It seems you're just trying to do `df.slice(0,2)` via a really long route through numpy.

Comment: This was part of a larger code snippet, where a number of dataframes with varying sizes would be split into a fixed number of parts (depending on what my computers working memory could handle) and then afterwards processed in parts through a for loop iteration.  I guess I could have also done that with df.slice() but for this instance np.array_split() seemed reasonably suited to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pandas appears to do something which ends up returning a Dataframe back from `np.array_split()`

```
>>> np.array_split(df.to_pandas(), 2)[0]
      column1 column2
0  2021-01-01  value1
1  2021-02-02  value2
2  2021-03-03  value3
```

Polars doesn't do this:

```
>>> np.array_split(df, 2)[0]
array([['2021-01-01', 'value1'],
       ['2021-02-02', 'value2'],
       ['2021-03-03', 'value3']], dtype=object)
```

Instead of `np.array_split` you could use the row count and modulo (`%`) to create groups:

```
df = pl.DataFrame({
    'column1': ['2021-01-01', '2021-02-02', '2021-03-03', '2021-04-04', '2021-05-05'],
    'column2': ['value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4', 'value5']
})

(df.with_row_count(offset=1)
   .with_columns(group = (pl.col('row_nr') % 2 != 0).cumsum())
)
```

```
shape: (5, 4)
┌────────┬────────────┬─────────┬───────┐
│ row_nr ┆ column1    ┆ column2 ┆ group │
│ ---    ┆ ---        ┆ ---     ┆ ---   │
│ u32    ┆ str        ┆ str     ┆ u32   │
╞════════╪════════════╪═════════╪═══════╡
│ 1      ┆ 2021-01-01 ┆ value1  ┆ 1     │
│ 2      ┆ 2021-02-02 ┆ value2  ┆ 1     │
│ 3      ┆ 2021-03-03 ┆ value3  ┆ 2     │
│ 4      ┆ 2021-04-04 ┆ value4  ┆ 2     │
│ 5      ┆ 2021-05-05 ┆ value5  ┆ 3     │
└────────┴────────────┴─────────┴───────┘
```

Depending on the goal, you could then use `.groupby()` or `.partition_by()` to split the dataframe.